# renderer2 append child node after parent node

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-renderer2

I want to append new child node `after` the parent node but `appendChild` appends it `inside` of it. Here is what I have:

My `component.html`:

```
<div id="parent" (click)="appendChild()">
    parent node
</div>
```

My `component.ts`:

```
private appendChild() {
    const div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    const text = this.renderer.createText('child node')
    this.renderer.appendChild(div, text);
    this.renderer.appendChild(document.getElementById("parent"), div)
}
```

This inserts new `div` that was created inside of `parent` node like this:

[image]

but how do I append it outside of `parent` node? Like this:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just insert it in elements parent

```
private appendChild() {
    const div = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    const text = this.renderer.createText('child node')
    this.renderer.appendChild(div, text);
    const parent = document.getElementById("parent")
    this.renderer.insertBefore(parent.parentElement, div, this.renderer.nextSibling(parent))
}
```